# Hadoop data pipeline usecase

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, spark-streaming

Here is my usecase :

- I've got some data stored in Hadoop (HDFS files then Hive views) which are ingested 5 times / day.
- I need to process these data (serviceA)
- Then, ASAP I need to put it back in Hadoop (to share the results with the community) and write it into an Oracle database (serviceB).

How can I do it ?

I've thought using Spark to get data from Hadoop, process it and write back in. But how can I update my Oracle database ? Constraints :

- No Scoop
- No API calls between serviceA and serviceB (large data)
- No direct writing from serviceA to serviceB database

Answer (score 1):

You can process data with Spark and store results back in HDFS/Hive table and once the results are ready you can use export data to Oracle using Sqoop

You can follow this simple [guide](http://www.insightcrunch.com/2016/10/sqoop-import-and-export-tables-from.html) to export data from Hive to Oracle; or follow [Sqoop guide](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html)

Comment: No other way possible ? (without Sqoop)

Answer (score 0):

If you use spark. 
you can just write using the spark JDBC. [see](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases)

From documentation:

```
// Saving data to a JDBC source
jdbcDF.write()
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
  .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "password")
  .save();
```

Comment: But I'm processing data from a serviceA and the Oracle database is the database of a serviceB  I don't want to directly write in the database from serviceA and don't want APIs too (large amount of data).

Comment: I don't understand you, you want to update DB without writing into it or calling service API ? Not sure what you mean, but maybe you want to write to some buffer such as Kafka topic and read it using service B and it will update it's own tables

Comment: Ideally I would like that serviceB could "knows" that some specific datas has been updated in HDFS/Hive OR a micro batch system, like every hour I'm loading these data in my database.

Comment: I would create a buffer table inside service B that only the spark writes to, and the service B is reading from. So every hour or so service B will check if it has new updated, and if it does just update internal tables + retention data lets say from yesterday .